# Nuxt using incorrect loader for scss

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, sass, nuxt.js

I am attempting to set up a nuxt project with scss. I added the following packages to my project:

```
    "sass": "^1.37.0",
    "sass-loader": "10",
```

and I updated `nuxt.config.js` to say the following to point to my new scss main file:

```
  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
      '~/assets/sass/main.scss'
  ],
```

I had to use older versions because i was getting errors with certain functions I was using but i managed to get it working correctly on my local machine, and it builds just fine repeatedly as I update code as well.

I am now trying to deploy to staging on a `Linux/nginx server` and I am getting the following errors when building `npm run build`:

```
ERROR in ./assets/sass/main.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-3!./assets/sass/main.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SyntaxError

(1:1) postcss-custom-properties: <css input> Unknown word

> 1 | var(--font-size-2)/var(--font-ratio)
    | ^
```

It looks like it's using css builder instead of sass builder! Does anyone know how to fix this? I doublechecked that the files on the server include the sass-loader and that the config is pointing to my .scss file, and i checked the documentation which states that Nuxt will automatically choose the correct loader.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `build: {
    extend(config) {
  config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      })
   
    }
  }` Try to manually adding rules to nuxt config. Is it working?

Comment: No, same issue with that added, i get the same error @FatimaMazhit

Comment: I think your error related to post-scss-custom properties, so it's not letting variables outside variables.scss file. You can paste all your variables to variables.scss file or  check this [https://github.com/nuxt-community/style-resources-module/issues/18#issuecomment-644627209](https://github.com/nuxt-community/style-resources-module/issues/18#issuecomment-644627209)